# Came up with this in the bar room meeting

Tags: word

Each clue has an associated word, use the associated words to give you the final answer.

Clue #1: Head, Green, Broken

Clue #2: Neck, Twist, Fighter

Clue #3: Theory, Quartet, Cheese

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Positive this was already basically answered by @marius and will delete if that answer gets undeleted but:

Clue #1: Head, Green, Broken

> Arrow (arrow head, green arrow, broken arrow)

Clue #2: Neck, Twist, Fighter

> Tie/Thai (neck tie, twist tie, thai fighter)

Clue #3: Theory, Quartet, Cheese

> String (string theory, string quartet, cheese string/string cheese)

Title: Came up with this in the bar room meeting

> Staff (bar staff, staff room, staff meeting)

Final Answer

> Bow/Bō (bow and arrow, bow tie, bow string, Bō staff)

Comment: Good work and nice answer. I did see @Marius post it earlier too.

Comment: For fighter in #2 I had star wars TIE rather than martial arts Thai

Comment: @Fillet +1 To my eternal shame I didn't even think of that!

Answer (score 3):

Clue #1: Head, Green, Broken

> Arrow

Clue #2: Neck, Twist, Fighter

> Bow

Clue #3: Theory, Quartet, Cheese

> String

Which gives us the answer:

> Archery